# How do I reveal properties and methods of a variable?

Tags: dart

I'm using a [pub](https://pub.dartlang.org) library that is lacking documentation.  One method returns a [Future](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/Future.html) value.  How do I reveal its available properties and methods without digging through the source code?

```dart
undocumentedMethod().then((unknown){
    print(unknown);  //How do I use this?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

undocumentedMethod().then((unknown){
    var r = reflect(unknown).type;  // ClassMirror
    var m = r.declarations;
    window.console.log(m);
});
```